# Magento 2: Migrate only Customer and orders

Tags: data-migration-tool, magento2.3.1

I want just migrate customer and orders from Magento 1 to Magento 2 how can I ignore other data like **cms page, block, products, etc.**
where do I need to change in config.xml?
**Magento 1 Version : 1.9.3.1

Magento 2 Version : 2.3.1**

Comment: What is your Magento 1 version?

Comment: 1.9.3.1 magento 1 and magento 2.3.1

Comment: Have you done it? I don't think we can upgrade directly from 1.9 to 2.3. You should move data from 1.9 to 2.3 and install other extensions/theme into 2.3 store.This migration tool can be helpful for you: [https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/](https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Install Data Migration Tool**

1. Check your Magento 2 version :- `sudo php bin/magento --version`
2. Install Data Migration Tool from repo.magento.com  :-

   composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
   composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<magento_version>
3. Configure Magento 2 Data Migration Tool :-

   ```
   1 The below file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open          Source platform.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource

   2 The below file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Commerce.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce

   3 The below file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Commerce to Magento 2 Commerce.
        <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce
   ```
4. Configuring the migration :-

   ```
   1 Change to the following directory :-
     <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<migration edition>/<ce or version>

   2 Rename config.xml.dist to config.xml 
     cp config.xml.dist config.xml

   3 Open config.xml in a text editor.

   4 Specify the following at minimum:

           <source>

               <database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

           </source>

           <destination>

               <database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

           </destination>

           <options>

               <crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>

           </options>
   ```
5. Migrate settings :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```
6. Migrate Data :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:data --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```
7. Migrate Delta :-

   ```
       php bin/magento migrate:delta --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
   ```

**Config.xml**

```
<steps mode="data">
     <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
     </step>

    <step title="Map Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
     </step>
     <step title="OrderGrids Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
     </step>
     <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
         <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
         <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
         <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
     </step>
</steps>
```

**As Per Your Requirement Config File Like This**

Comment: its work for me thank @ronak

Comment: hi @Rathod, Above steps worked fine, can you please update how to migrate only Products?

Comment: This kills all options previously added to product attributes (dropdown, multiselect) in the m2 database.

Comment: Already done with the data migration, need to add remaining Orders and Customers data. Can anyone describe in a detailed process to proceed it?

Comment: Is the 5th step required? Can i ommit the 5th step and proceed with data migration and delta migration afterwards?

Comment: Does not work, it also migrates CMS Sites and products

Comment: any changes we are doing in the options tag of the config.xml except the crypt_key? Please share the details

Answer (score 1):

Please do the changes in the `data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.1/config.xml`. You can rename the config.xml.dist to config.xml. You can comment out all other steps except these. Please follow this for detailed instruction https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

```
<steps mode="data">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
         <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
</steps>
```

If you want delta migration to be performed(migrating recent data after last migration) please configure this

```
<steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
</steps>
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284577/magento-2-customer-data-migration-volume-check-failed   can u help me on this issue

Comment: I need help on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/335244/migrate-custom-module-magento-1-9-x-to-magento-2-4-1 Migration of custom modules.

Comment: Does not work, it also migrates CMS Sites and products

Answer (score 0):

This process is working pretty well in 2.4.6; I however am having some issues with the following "not mapped" and "mismatched" data. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on how to ignore or resolve the following.

Here are my Warnings that I would like to ignore in the map.xml.

[WARNING]: Destination fields are not mapped. Document: customer_entity. Fields: mp_smtp_email_marketing_synced

[WARNING]: Source documents are not mapped: amasty_geoip_block_6392c64add4bf

[WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order. Fields: referrer

[WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: salesrule. Fields: allow_multiple_coupons

[WARNING]: Destination fields are not mapped. Document: importexport_importdata. Fields: is_processed,updated_at

[WARNING]: Destination fields are not mapped. Document: newsletter_subscriber. Fields: mp_smtp_email_marketing_synced

[WARNING]: Destination fields are not mapped. Document: quote. Fields: magecomp_order_comment,um_order_comment,mp_smtp_ace_token,mp_smtp_ace_sent,mp_smtp_ace_log_ids,mp_smtp_ace_log_data

[[WARNING]: Destination fields are not mapped. Document: sales_order. Fields: magecomp_order_comment,um_order_comment,mp_smtp_email_marketing_synced,mp_smtp_email_marketing_order_created

[WARNING]: Destination fields are not mapped. Document: search_query. Fields: is_spellchecked

[WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Source document: sales_flat_order_item. Fields: product_options

[WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Source document: sales_flat_quote. Fields: customer_note

[WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Destination document: quote. Fields: customer_note

[WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Destination document: sales_order_item. Fields: product_options

I was able to ignore a ton of unused attributes by using the following format, but for the above items, it is not working.

```
<ignore>
    <document>zero1_seoredirects_redirection_cache</document>
</ignore>
```