# How can we migrate only customers, products and orders data using Data Migration tool?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool

I am using Magento 2.3 version. Is it possible to migrate only customers, products and orders data from Magento 1 site using Data Migration tool? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268804/magento-2-migrate-only-customer-and-orders

Comment: @MohitPatel Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You can definitely fulfill your quest using our Magento migration package. Don't hesitate to try a free demo on our website.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the data you want to migrate by following the tool configuration listed here on the Magento Docs site

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

There are also a number of videos from Adobe that describe the process.

Remember that after you have done your initial migration, you can not do a delta on your products