# How to move orders from Magento 1.9.4 to Magento 2.4.5-p1?

Tags: orders, importexport

**How on Earth am I meant to move orders from Magento 1.9.4 to Magento 2.4.5-p1?**

Someone suggested the '*Improved Import & Export for Magento 2*':

https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html

I've reached out to them regarding exporting the orders first from Magento 1.9.4 and they explained that they have an extension for that for Magento 1.x but they are no longer providing any support for it:

https://github.com/firebearstudio/iimagento1

I finally got it installed, but **it does not appear to have any Export functionality whatsoever!** Only the following options appear:

**Firebear
Improved Import**

```
General

Product Images Import

Product Custom Options Import

Product Tier Prices Import

Customers password import

Export multiple product images
```

Now, I was thinking their extension would EXPORT the data (orders) in the same format from Magento 1.9.4 as their 'Improved Import & Export for Magento 2' requires on the IMPORT on the side of Magento 2.4.5-p1. I've reached out to them but I am not holding my breath as their support seems to be the worst I've ever come across (generally don't care, answer simple question days later etc.)

**What are other options for the Order migration from 1.9.4 to 2.4.5-p1?** I see there is a Magento native Orders Export in:

```
- Sales >> Orders >> Export to CSV EXPORT
```

**If I export the orders this way, what extension or process can I follow to IMPORT those orders on Magento 2.4.5-p1? I would really prefer NOT to use the official Magento Migration Tool as it badly messed up another Magento instance for us but worse case, I will do that - is it possible to use the tool for orders only and would that be safe?** *Any other suggestions will be greatly appreciated!*

[image]

[image]

Comment: A good option is using Magento Data Migration tool.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to accomplish this is by using the Magento Migration Tool. To ensure a smooth process, you can follow the steps below:

### Steps:-

1. Set up a fresh Magento installation with version 2.4.5-p1.
2. Import your Magento 1 database into the same location.
3. Configure the Magento Migration Tool.

> To configure the migration tool, you can refer to the following answer
> on Magento Stack Exchange:
> [Magento 2: Migrate only Customer and orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268804/magento-2-migrate-only-customer-and-orders)

4. Configure the migration tool specifically for migrating sales orders.
5. After the migration is complete, export the sales order data from the migrated Magento 2 database table and import it into your project instantly **(NOTE:- Just take a data from the Migrated DB not whole table).**

**For step 5 I have created one script which you can use,**

Put migrated database at same location where you need to add orders data,

Create one script to perform the order data import from the migrated database.

## Script

```
<?php
class ImportSalesData 
{
    protected $importTables = [
        "quote",
        "quote_address",
        "quote_address_item",
        "quote_id_mask",
        "quote_item",
        "quote_item_option",
        "quote_payment",
        "quote_shipping_rate",
        "sales_order",
        "sales_order_address",
        "sales_order_aggregated_created",
        "sales_order_aggregated_updated",
        "sales_order_grid",
        "sales_order_item",
        "sales_order_payment",
        "sales_order_status",
        "sales_order_status_history",
        "sales_order_status_label",
        "sales_order_status_state",
        "sales_order_tax",
        "sales_order_tax_item",
        "sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily",
        "sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly",
        "sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly",
        "sales_invoice",
        "sales_invoiced_aggregated",
        "sales_invoiced_aggregated_order",
        "sales_invoice_comment",
        "sales_invoice_grid",
        "sales_invoice_item",
        "sales_payment_transaction",
        "sales_sequence_meta",
        "sales_sequence_profile",
        "sales_shipping_aggregated",
        "sales_shipping_aggregated_order"
    ];

    public function execute() { 

        $dbConnection = $this->dataBaseConnection([
            'host' => "YOU_HOST", 
            'dbname' => "DB_NAME",  
            'username' => "USER_NAME", 
            'password' => "PASSWORD"
        ]);

        $this->importMigratedData($dbConnection);
    }

    private function importMigratedData($dbConnection) {
        $checkFor = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0";
        $dbConnection->query($checkFor);
        foreach ($this->importTables as $_importTable) {
            try {
                $truncateTableSql = "TRUNCATE table ".$_importTable;
                $dbConnection->query($truncateTableSql);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                
            }
        }
        $checkFor = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1";
        $dbConnection->query($checkFor);

        foreach($this->importTables as $_table) {
            try {
                $coulumns = $dbConnection->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$this->destinationDbName.".".$_table)->fetchAll();
                $tableCol = [];
                foreach ($coulumns as $_coulumns) {
                    $tableCol[] = $_coulumns['Field'];
                }  
                $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $this->toBeLiveDbName ."." . $_table ." (" . implode(',', $tableCol) . ") SELECT ". implode(',', $tableCol) ." FROM ". $this->destinationDbName . "." . $_table;
                $dbConnection->query($sql);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
                echo $_table."\n";
            }
        }
    }

    private function dataBaseConnection($dbConnection) {
        try {
            if (isset($dbConnection['user'])) {
                $dbConnection['username'] = $dbConnection['user'];
                unset($dbConnection['user']);
            }
            if (isset($dbConnection['name'])) {
                $dbConnection['dbname'] = $dbConnection['name'];
                unset($dbConnection['name']);
            }
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $connectionFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\ConnectionFactory');
            $liveConnection = $connectionFactory->create($dbConnection)->getConnection();
            return $liveConnection;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

After creation above script create object of the **ImportSalesData** and call **execute()** function.

**NOTE:-** DO NOT CHANGE THE ORDER OF THE TABLES WHICH ARE DEFINE IN THE **$importTables** VARIABLE.

By following these steps, you can successfully migrate only the sales order data from Magento 1 to Magento 2 while avoiding any potential issues.

Comment: This is brilliant! You are so smart - what a great workaround! I can do everything you wrote except for STEP #5 :-( Would you please help by posting the exact steps on how to do #5 step by step? I have access to phpMYADMIN.

Comment: @Allysin, I have updated the answer. Please review it and let me know if it works for you. If it does, please accept this answer to help others find a better solution.

Comment: @Allysin is it works for you?